# Передача сообщения от приложения в сеть

Tags: сеть

как происходит последовательная передача сообщения от приложения в сеть?

Меня интересует полный путь с учетом всех программных и аппаратных средств, где принимает участие в передаче приложение, API, ОП, сетевые уровни, драйвера, ИК

Как происходит полный цикл, что за чем идет?

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но есть подозрение, что для Stack Overflow он слишком общий

Comment: Вам полностью по модели OSI? Длинненький маршрут будет